# How to add and run two activities in android studio without using a button?

Tags: android

I am developing an app.I want to add two activities in my app one i want be the launch page time activity and another activity is app activity.I have successfully built these two activities but how to setup these two activities to run one after another.

Comment: you mean splash screen?

Comment: check my ans and ask me in case of any query

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Answer (score 1):

try this it can help you

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, 3000);// it will start you activity after 3 seconds
```

for more information [Click here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the operable term here is a "Splash screen". You should start your app with the splash screen activity, then create a timer in the onCreate method That will start your app activity after a specified duration. No click required.

You can take a look at this implementation http://pcessflight.com/smart-android-splash-screen-grabbing-permissions/